# jQuery colorbox onclose update parent

Tags: jquery, forms, colorbox

Could do with some help you guys.

So I'm using jQuery colorbox and its activated by clicking a link. In the colorbox there is a form with some checkboxes, what I would like to do is to get all the values of the selected checkboxes into the parent when submit is clicked (and close colorbox subsequently). I don't want the parent window to refresh. It should automatically populate the "Checkbox Items from Colorbox" with the contents

Here is the link http://tdesigns.net84.net/colorbox/example1/

```
Parent code

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'/>
        <title>ColorBox Examples</title>
        <style>
            body{font:12px/1.2 Verdana, sans-serif; padding:0 10px;}
            a:link, a:visited{text-decoration:none; color:#416CE5; border-bottom:1px solid #416CE5;}
            h2{font-size:13px; margin:15px 0 0 0;}
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"400px", height:"400px"});                
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a class='iframe' href="../content/ajax.html">Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a></p>
        <p>
            Checkbox Items from Colorbox
        </p>
    </body>
</html>

popup code

<form action="" method="post">
    Choose a country 
    <br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="UK" />UK<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="USA" />USA<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="Japan" />Japan<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="China" />China<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="Australia" />Australia
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Would really appreciate it if I could get some help with this.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Post code here or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: updated it with the code @ChrisPratt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by adding the following function in your `ajax.html` file

First load jQuery in that file and then add this document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#form').submit(function(){

                    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                        window.parent.$("#text").text(parent.$("#text").text() + $(this).val()+" ,");

                    });
                    parent.$.colorbox.close();
                    return false;
        });             
    });
```

What this is doing is when user clicks on the `submit button` on `overlay iframe` it takes all checked checkbox add those values into parent window's text div and then close the colorbox window.

Here's the modified code for `ajax.html` file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" id='form'>
    Choose a country 
    <br /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="UK" />UK<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="USA" />USA<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="Japan" />Japan<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="China" />China<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="countryCheckbox[]" value="Australia" />Australia
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#form').submit(function(){

                    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                        window.parent.$("#text").text(parent.$("#text").text() + $(this).val()+" ,");

                    });
                    parent.$.colorbox.close();
                    return false;
        });             
    });
</script>
```

Also add an id to the paragraph where value will be added like this

```
<p id="text">
    Checkbox Items from Colorbox: 
</p>
```

You have to run the code from `localhost` or same `virtualhost` if you have any or it will not allow accessing parent from `child iframe`. Just drop the modified files in a folder in your `document root` and access it through browser. Let me know if it works.

here's a working demo http://joynag.net/demos/colorbox/