# get checkbox values from popup and display in unordered list on parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, popup

I am using **Colorbox Jquery popup** for opening a **form** which is having multiple chekboxes and submit button.

HTML code:

```
  <div class="form-row addlink ng-binding" ng-bind-html="question.getText()"><em><a class='inline' href="#inline_content">+ Add/Edit</a></em></div>

    <div class="form-row added ng-binding" ng-bind-html="question.getText()" id="text"></div>

 <!-- This contains the hidden content for inline calls (POPUP code)-->
    <div style='display:none'>
        <div id='inline_content' style='padding:15px; background:#fff; font-size: 17px;'>
        <form action="" id="popup_form">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="race" value="American Indian or Alaska Native"> American Indian or Alaska Native<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="race" value="Asian"> Asian<br> 
                    <input type="checkbox" name="race" value="Black or African American"> Black or African American<br> 
                    <input type="checkbox" name="race" value="Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander"> Native Hawaiian or Other Pacific Islander<br> 
                    <input type="checkbox" name="race" value="White"> White<br> 
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submitbtn" value="Add">
           </form>

       </div>
    </div>
```

If user clicks on *+Add/Edit* link then popup will open. Then the selected values of checkboxes will display on parent page after submit click. To display values of checkboxes on parent page I have used following script.

Script:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#popup_form').submit(function(){

                    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
                          $("#text").text($("#text").text() + $(this).val()+ " ,");

                    });
                    parent.$.colorbox.close();
                    return false;
        });             
    });
</script>
```

Now what is happening,

1) if I checked e.g. first two checkboxes that values are displaying like this : `American Indian or Alaska Native ,Asian ,` . If again I open popup to select 3rd checkbox then popup shows first two values checked with result like `American Indian or Alaska Native ,Asian ,American Indian or Alaska Native ,Asian ,Black or African American ,` where I just want to display `American Indian or Alaska Native ,Asian ,Black or African American ,`

why the result is getting repeated?

2) How I can show the result in un-ordered list(in bullet and text format e.g. using `<ul><li>`) on parent page?

Comment: $('input:checkbox:checked'). Is that the right way to select a checkbox. Use correct attribute selector - https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: @ Thilak Rao: I can't say that as I am new to the javascript. I have tried some stackoverflow answers like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654850/jquery-colorbox-onclose-update-parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :You are trying to add text to the previously present text that is where data is duplicating. Instead you can store the selected checkbox data in a string and then replace that string to the text of the div.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            //array to store checkbox values
            checkValues = new Array();

            $('#popup_form').submit(function(){
                        //capture all text in a variable
                        var textStr = $('<ul></ul>');
                        //iterate all checkbox values to create ul
                        $.each(checkValues, function( index, value ){
                              textStr.append('<li>'+value+'</li>');
                        });
                        //add text
                        $("#text").html(textStr);
                        parent.$.colorbox.close();
                        return false;
            });

             //add change handler for checkbox        
           $('input:checkbox[name=race]').change(function(){
               value = $(this).val();
               if(this.checked)
                   checkValues.push(value);
               else
               {   //Removing by value
                  checkValues = $.grep(checkValues, function(n, i) { 
                      return n !== value;
                  }); 
               }
          });             
  });
```

Comment: @ Bhushan Kawadkar: Cool..:) its not replicating now. result is like this: `American Indian or Alaska NativeAsianBlack or African American`. Can you please suggest me how I can display result in proper un-ordered list?

Comment: Unordered means you want to show list as per the sequence of checkbox checked and not the actual sequence of checkbox in html, right?

Comment: yaah, as the user checks the check boxes(user can check any) the result should be display in un-ordered list means bullet and text as such(`<ul><li>`).

Comment: @ Bhushan Kawadkar: ` textStr.append('<li>'+value+'</li>');` getting error at this line.

Comment: @ Bhushan Kawadkar: opening `{` was missing. now result is like this: `[object Object]`

Comment: yeah your are correct i missed the `{` and to print li properly need to call `.html()` instead of `.text()`, pls see my updated answer